# Executing Sample Flink Program in Local

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am trying to execute a sample program in Apache Flink in local mode.

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;


public class WordCountExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        DataSet<String> text = env.fromElements(
            "Who's there?",
            "I think I hear them. Stand, ho! Who's there?");
        //DataSet<String> text1 = env.readTextFile(args[0]);

        DataSet<Tuple2<String, Integer>> wordCounts = text
            .flatMap(new LineSplitter())
            .groupBy(0)
            .sum(1);

        wordCounts.print();
        env.execute();

        env.execute("Word Count Example");
    }

    public static class LineSplitter implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {
        @Override
        public void flatMap(String line, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) {
            for (String word : line.split(" ")) {
                out.collect(new Tuple2<String, Integer>(word, 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is giving me exception :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat
    at WordCountExample.main(WordCountExample.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have used the correct jars also.
**flink-java-0.9.0-milestone-1.jar
flink-clients-0.9.0-milestone-1.jar
flink-core-0.9.0-milestone-1.jar**

Comment: How exactly do you execute the program? Are you running it from an IDE, via the CLI client or web-submission client?

Comment: I am running it from the IDE, running it as a normal java application.

Comment: As in the documentation it is given..that I can run it directly in local mode in desktop

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation page?

Comment: http://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/programming_guide.html

Answer (score 8):

Adding the three Flink Jar files as dependencies in your project is not enough because they have other transitive dependencies, for example on Hadoop.

The easiest way to get a working setup to develop (and locally execute) Flink programs is to follow the [quickstart guide](http://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/quickstart/java_api_quickstart.html) which uses a Maven archetype to configure a Maven project. This Maven project can be imported into your IDE.

Answer (score 2):

NoClassDefFoundError extends LinkageError

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
>   load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
>   as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
>   definition of the class could be found. The searched-for class
>   definition existed when the currently executing class was compiled,
>   but the definition can no longer be found.

Your code/jar dependent to hadoop. Found it here download jar file and add it in your classpath [org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhadoopmapred0210jar.htm)

Comment: I am running my code locally. The environment should be set to local and not in hadoop mode. Thats why I am confused here.

Comment: flink is dependent on hadoop, make sure you have correct jar file, reference https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html **OR** http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.flink/flink-java/0.9.0-milestone-1-hadoop1

Comment: it is not dependent on hadoop sir. There are jars availaible for flink that are hadoop indepedent.

Comment: WordCountExample.java:10 Expects org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat the main cause of your exception. What is on line 10?

Comment: final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly,** the flink jar files which you have included in your project are not enough, include all the jar files which are present in the **lib** folder present under the flink's source folder.

**Secondly,** *" env.execute();
            env.execute("Word Count Example");"* These lines of code are not required since you are just printing your dataset onto the console; you're not writing the output into a file(.txt, .csv etc.). So, better to remove these lines (Sometimes throws errors if included in code if not required *(observed a lot of times)*)

**Thirdly,** while exporting the jar files for your Java Project from your IDE, don't forget to select your 'Main' class.

Hopefully, after making the above changes, your code works.